# c# Load image in Radgrid dynamically from database

Tags: c#, telerik

I am trying to create and load a radgrid dynamically from database.How can I load an image dynamically using templatecolumn?

I am using a datatable to bind data

Thanks in advance

Comment: by from database , you mean Dbml and linQ or hand made querry ?

Comment: I am using linq

Comment: Give me 5 minutes tops for a full post. but the short answer is RadBinaryImage You can read the doc while im writing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Adding [RadBinaryImage](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/radbinaryimage) in a Rad Grid.

In your GridTemplatedColumn, add a RadBinaryImage.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="MyField" DataField="MyField">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RIB_dsds"
                            ImageUrl="~/Site/Images/kiterror.png"
                            DataValue='<%# ((Type)Container.DataItem).MyPhoto %>'
                            AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false"
                            Width="60px" Height="60px"
                            ToolTip='<%# string.Format("Photo of {0}",((Type)Container.DataItem).PhotoLabel) %>'
                            AlternateText='<%# string.Format("Photo of {0}",((Type)Container.DataItem).CPS_PhotoLabel) %>' />
```

A little trick have been use here, Setting the ImageUrl to a default image Before setting the DataValue Makes the Default Image Appear only if DataValue is NULL

In Your DBML, You must change the field MyPhoto into `Byte() ( System.Byte[])`.
Click on your Dbml , Click on the field . Properties and use the Type dropdown list to select the good type.

#### Edit: As your question was about doing it [programmaticaly](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/creating-a-radgrid-programmatically#creating-template-columns-programm).

Comment: Thanks Pierre,... But as I said I am creating the grid only on server side, I am creating a generic grid for different reports. So the columns are not fixed.

Comment: Well im a bit confuse. Creating Templated Column programmatically is a pain. Because for the control inside the Templated to persis the control you have to be in  Page_init at least.

Comment: I have a question: Same page ? Different report but same data ? I mean many column in data but only a few by report. I m trying to understand what you want to see if this can be achiev with an easier path. Like multiple grid set into your page and in pageload hide n show the wanted one.

Comment: I have update with the Documentation about creating template columns programmatically. And this always looked like a pain for me. So why do you need programmatically created Grid. I'm pretty sure i can figure a work around in your case.

Comment: The reason I didnt go with multiple grid set is I wanted to create a generic grid so that changes columns in future can easily fit in.

Comment: And yes programatically generating is a pain... I am just looking if there are easier options. :) any way thanks for the help

Comment: Adding or changing anything in a column look easier in the frontpage than in code behind for me. But with the documentation about programmatical templated colmun im pretty sure its doable. But i have done it before. So i will be glad to help on your next question if you have issue creating in.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it dynamically.Here is the code.

While creating the column I created it as a template column with an unique ID
`GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
                    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
                    templateColumn.DataField = <Column Name from DB>;
                    templateColumn.HeaderText = <Column Name from DB>;
                    templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new MyTemplate(<Column Name from DB>);
                    columnList.Add(<Column Name from DB>);//add column to grid
                    dt.Columns.Add(<Column Name from DB>);//add column to datatable`

`private class MyTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image pic;
        private string colname;
        public MyTemplate(string cName)
        {
            colname = cName;
        }
        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            pic = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            pic.ID = "img_" + colname;\\create an Id for the column(colname is same as DB value for column)
            container.Controls.Add(pic);
        }
   }`

and while loading image from database

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image pic = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
 pic = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)item.FindControl("img_" + <Column Name from DB>)\\access by Id created for column;
pic.ImageUrl = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageString);`